# Menu with sublevels on hover using CSS only

Tags: html, css, menu

I want to know if it is possible, with pure html and css (no javascript, htc files, ...), to create a menu that has a sort of dropdown effect for subitems.
It doesn't have to slide or anything (I know thats impossible), just show on hover.

Edit: It has to work in IE.

Thanks!

Comment: It is possible if you don't care about IE, and don't care about introducing accessibility problems for people with motor skill related handicaps (such as arthritis can introduce) and don't care about making the submenus inaccessible to people who don't use a pointing device. i.e. its a really bad idea.

Comment: I've tried googling it but couldn't find any descent example. I don't want to use javascript because the submenu's aren't shown anywhere else. People who don't have javascript will not be able to view these then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at this pure css menu creator:
[purecssmenu.com](http://purecssmenu.com/)

Comment: this is awesome! thanks, exactly what I was looking for and more!

Comment: Isn't it a javascript based one?

Comment: In downloaded it and it gives you a zipfile with an html and some images. The html file only contains html and css, no javascript to be found! Plus, it works great in IE8, dunno about IE6. Anyone care to test?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at

[Pure Css Dropdown Menu Without Using Javascript](http://aceinfowayindia.com/blog/2009/07/pure-css-dropdown-menu-without-useing-javascript/)

[GRC's Script-Free Pure-CSS Menuing System](http://www.grc.com/menu2/invitro.htm)

[CSS menus](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/testMenu.html)

[100% Pure CSS Menu without Javascript](http://www.cafewebmaster.com/pure-css-mouseover-menu-without-javascript)

I would also like to know why you don't want JavaScript.

Comment: Why I don't want Javascript? Because I want the website to reach as many people as possible. +-5% of the users on the internet have javascript disabled or use browsers that do not support it.

Answer (score 0):

I've tackled this a couple of times.. I wanted pure CSS as well that was layed out using UL's and LI's. It took me a while and a lot of reading and I ended up writing my own based on the source of a lot of others. Unfortunately, I had to make sure it worked in IE6 as well..

This site has a lot of good examples: [CSSPlay](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/final_drop.html)

As well, you might look at the source for this one: [CSS Menus](http://www.seoconsultants.com/css/menus/horizontal/)

Mine ended up being a combination of several.

Answer (score 0):

It's very common drop down CSS menu. Look here http://menu.so/product-category/css-menu/dropdown-css-menu

The hover-show effect is made with `li>ul{display:none} li:hover>ul{display:block;}` selector.